# Merging multiple Google Calendar feeds for display on my desktop

Tags: windows, google-calendar-api

I have several Google calendars that I'd like to merge and place on my windows desktop using [Samurize](http://www.samurize.com/). I've tried using Samurize's Page Scraper plugin, but it doesn't appear to be up to the task.

I can get Samurize to run a script and place it's output on the desktop, but I'm not sure 
what the best tools are to do this.

All the URLs I have are of the form:

```
http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/example%40gmail.com/private-REMOVED/basic?futureevents=true&orderby=starttime&sortorder=ascending&singleevents=true
```

So I could fetch them using curl, but then I need to filter them.

I want something that looks like:

```
2009 12 02  Event from calendar 1's description 
2009 12 03  Event from calendar 2's description 
2009 12 04  Event from calendar 1's description 
2009 12 05  Event from calendar 3's description 
2009 12 06  Event from calendar 1's description
```

However the dates in the calendar feeds are formatted like this:

```
<title type='html'>Event from calendar 1's description</title><summary type='html'>When: Fri 5 Dec 2008&lt;br&gt;
```

**So how do I filter out the dates and descriptions, and convert the dates?**

(I have cygwin installed so something using perl or sed/awk would be perfect as I'm familiar enough with them that I'd be confident about altering them in future, but I'm open to suggestions.)

Comment: Thanks Joel, for some reason Firefox won't remember to spell check the Title input and I'd just assumed it had.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on John W's script this is what I'm using

```
#!c:\cygwin\bin\perl.exe -w
use strict;
use LWP::Simple qw(get);

my %calendars = ( "Sam Hasler", "http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/blah/blah/basic"
                , "Family    ", "http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/blah/blah/basic"
                , "Work      ", "http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/blah/blah/basic"
                );

my $params = "?futureevents=true&orderby=starttime&sortorder=ascending&singleevents=true";

my %months = ( "Jan", "01", "Feb", "02", "Mar", "03", "Apr", "04"
             , "May", "05", "Jun", "06", "Jul", "07", "Aug", "08"
             , "Sep", "09", "Oct", "10", "Nov", "11", "Dec", "12");

my $calendar_name;
my $calendar_url;
my @lines;

while (($calendar_name, $calendar_url) = each(%calendars)){
    my $calendar_data = get "$calendar_url$params";
    @lines = split(/\n/, $calendar_data);

    foreach (@lines) {
        if (/<title type='html'>([\d\D]*)<\/title><summary type='html'>When: (\S+) (\S+) (\S+) (\S+)&lt;br&gt;/)
        {
            my $day = "$3";
            if ($3 < 10 ) {
                $day = "0$3";
            }

            print "$5 $months{$4} $day\t$calendar_name\t$1\n";
        }
    }

}
```

I just pipe the output through `sort` to get it in date order.

**Update:** I've converted my script to a plugin and submitted it to the Samurize website: [Merge Google Calendar feeds](http://www.samurize.com/modules/mydownloads/singlefile.php?cid=7&lid=2287).

Comment: The only thing this doesn't handle is converting  &amp; entities in the descriptions.

Comment: Sam, glad I could help!  You may be able to add something like my $description = $1; $description =~ s/&amp;/&/g; to take care of the encoded ampersands.

Answer (score 1):

I'm learning perl so please don't laugh too hard, but here's something that might get you most of the way towards parsing:

```
#!C:\Perl\bin -w
use strict;

my %months = ("Jan", "01", "Feb", "02", "Mar", "03", ... etc. etc. ... "Dec", "12");

$_ = "<title type='html'>Event from calendar 1's description</title><summary type='html'>When: Fri 5 Dec 2008<br>";

if (/<title type='html'>([\d\D]*)<\/title><summary type='html'>When: (\S+) (\S+) (\S+) (\S+)<br>/)
{
    print "$5 $months{$4} $3 $1\n";
}
```

Comment: that looks promising, I'll try it out and get back to you.

Comment: Just be sure to fill out the rest of the hash. ;)

Comment: Thanks, I was able to get something that worked exactly how I wanted it to. See my answer for the script I ended up using

Answer (score 1):

Two ideas.

You could use Yahoo Pipes (see [this article](http://ouseful.wordpress.com/2008/12/06/merging-several-calendar-ical-feeds-with-yahoo-pipes/).)

Or, if you don't want to wait around for Yahoo to refresh it's data, [here](http://code.google.com/p/merge-ics/) is a python script under development to merge ICAL files.

Comment: I'm using the xml feeds because with parameters you can get it to output recurring events more than once.